# Oracle NetSuite Integration

Tags: integration, oracle, netsuite

We are working with Oracle on a Netsuite integration and they are inquiring for our Salesforce authentication credentials. When I asked them to clarify what they required and how to get it, they were unable to give any straight answers as to how to go about getting this but rather told us to submit a query with Salesforce Support to help us.

I submitted the query with Salesforce Support and they informed us they were unable to assist either so we're now at a loss of how to obtain these authentication credentials.

Any help in this situation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are lots of ways a 3rd party can integrate with SFDC but for starters, you should set up a dedicated user `netsuite-integration@mycompany.com` and then ask for their doc on what OAuth methods they support for the integration. In most cases, you'll need to set up a Connected App